# Rotman's Introduction to Algebraic Topology Question 1.5

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am a bit confused by the wording of this exercise

> Let $X = \lbrace 0 \rbrace \cup \lbrace 1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots, 1/n, \dots \rbrace$ and Y be a countable discrete space. Show that $X,Y$ don't have the same homotopy type.

Isn't $X$ a countable discrete space? Also, the hint on this exercise says to use $X$'s compactness. How is $X$ compact? Doesn't the open cover of each singleton not admit a finite subcover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotman does not give the topology of $X$.  An educated guess is that $X$ is meant to have the subspace topology as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  This is consistent with the compactness hint because any open subset containing $0$ contains all but finitely many other points.

Comment: Ah, so then $X$ would be a countable discrete space if it was equipped with the discrete topology?

Comment: Yes.  I think the point of this exercise is to demonstrate that changing the topology of space in a relatively small way can give different homotopy types.  ($X$ is the one-point compactification of $Y$.)

Comment: terrific, thank you